Parser with antlr4 in Java
I want to parse this with Java and ANTRL4:
; comment
[WORLD]

[game] ; is a chilf of WORLD
Name=The Game ; needs a string

[/game] ; end of game

[/WORLD] ; end of WORLD


grammar GameData;

// Whitespace and comments (ignored)
WS  : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
COMMENT     : ';' .*? ('\r'? '\n' | EOF) -> skip;

WORLD   : '[Ww] [Oo] [Rr] [Ll] [Dd]';
GAME    : '[Gg] [Aa] [Mm] [Ee]';


// Header and closing
header     : '[' WORLD ']' ;
closing    : '[' '/' WORLD ']' ;

// Section (game in this case)
game_section    : '[' GAME ']' ( keyValuePair )* ;

// Key-value pair
keyValuePair : ID '=' value ';' ;

// Value (string in this case)
value       : STRING ;

// Terminals
DOT      : '.';
ID       : [a-zA-Z]+;
STRING    : '"' .*? '"' ;

file        : (header|game_section)*;

But I can't get the Name.
This is my Java code:
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.*;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.*;
import parser.*;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Create an input stream from your GameData file

        CharStream input = CharStreams.fromFileName("test.bd");

        // Create a lexer that feeds off of input CharStream

        GameDataLexer lexer = new GameDataLexer(input);
        // Create a buffer of tokens pulled from the lexer
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);

        // Create a parser that feeds off the tokens buffer
        GameDataParser parser = new GameDataParser(tokens);
        // Start parsing at the 'file' rule
        ParseTree tree = parser.file();

        System.out.println("getChildCount "+tree.getChildCount());
        for(int i=0;i<tree.getChildCount();i++) 
            System.out.println("getChild "+tree.getChild(i).toString());
        System.out.println(tree.toStringTree(parser));
        
    }

This is the output:
line 2:1 no viable alternative at input '[WORLD'
getChildCount 18
getChild [
getChild WORLD
getChild ]
getChild [
getChild game
getChild ]
getChild Name
getChild =
getChild The
getChild Game
getChild [
getChild /
getChild game
getChild ]
getChild [
getChild /
getChild WORLD
getChild ]
(file [ WORLD ] [ game ] Name = The Game [ / game ] [ / WORLD ])



WORLD   : '[Bb] [Dd] [Cc] [Ff] [Ff]'; looks odd... shouldn't those chars spell "world"?

@Thomas, I'm very sorry. This was old. But the problem is the same.

I think you're also missing some closing tokens and maybe also move comments and whitespace to the end as rules are applied top-down. Then game_section should probably be '[' GAME ']'  ( keyValuePair )* '[/' GAME ']' and file should be header game_section closing. Also note that value requires STRING which in turn is defined to be surrounded by double quotes. Thus Name=The Game would have to be Name="The Game".


WORLD   : '[Bb] [Dd] [Cc] [Ff] [Ff]';
GAME    : '[Gg] [Aa] [Mm] [Ee]';


This is not correct: it should be without quotes, and WORLD should be wiht the proper characters:
WORLD   : [Ww] [Oo] [Rr] [Ll] [Dd];
GAME    : [Gg] [Aa] [Mm] [Ee];

Looking at your rules:

// Key-value pair
keyValuePair : ID '=' value ';' ;

// Value (string in this case)
value       : STRING ;


and input:

Name=The Game ; needs a string


the keyValuePair should be without a ; because that is treated as part of a comment in the lexer. Also, the input is expected to have quotes: Name="The Game"
Finally, you never seem to be using the closing. I'd expect to see file include this:
file : header game_section* closing EOF;

EDIT
Something like this:
grammar GameData;

file         : header game_section* closing EOF;
header       : '[' WORLD ']' ;
closing      : '[/' WORLD ']' ;
game_section : '[' GAME ']' keyValuePair* '[/' GAME ']';
keyValuePair : ID '=' value ;
value        : STRING ;

WS      : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
COMMENT : ';' ~[\r\n]* -> skip;
WORLD   : [Ww] [Oo] [Rr] [Ll] [Dd];
GAME    : [Gg] [Aa] [Mm] [Ee];
DOT     : '.';
ID      : [a-zA-Z]+;
STRING  : '"' .*? '"';

seems to work for the input:
; comment
[WORLD]

[game] ; is a chilf of WORLD
Name="The Game" ; needs a string

[/game] ; end of game

[/WORLD] ; end of WORLD

EDIT 2
Without the quotes, it could look like this:
grammar GameData;

file         : header game_section* closing EOF;
header       : '[' WORLD ']' ;
closing      : '[/' WORLD ']' ;
game_section : '[' GAME ']' keyValuePair* '[/' GAME ']';
keyValuePair : ID '=' value ;
value        : word+;
word         : ID | GAME | WORLD;

WS      : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
COMMENT : ';' ~[\r\n]* -> skip;
WORLD   : [Ww] [Oo] [Rr] [Ll] [Dd];
GAME    : [Gg] [Aa] [Mm] [Ee];
DOT     : '.';
ID      : [a-zA-Z]+;

Note that the word rule now needs to include all tokens that might be considered a part of the value (so also keywords!).

Thank you. This works well. But how can I do it without quotes?

Check my EDIT 2

Now I put in a number into the Name value.
...
Name=The Test123 ; needs a string
...
and I changed the grammar to this:
grammar GameData; ... word         : ID | STRING | GAME | WORLD;       ... ... STRING  : .+?;
But I get this error: line 1:2 mismatched input 'WORLD' expecting GAME

That is a whole different issue. Feel free to create a new question for it: these small comment boxes are not well suited for Q&A's.
